# ARIMA estimate validation through arima.sim

Tags: r, time-series, arima, arma

This is out of my curiosity trying to compare time series input to an ARMA model and reconstructed series after an ARMA estimate is obtained. These are the steps I am thinking:

1. Construct simulation time series

   ```
   arma.sim <- arima.sim(model=list(ar=c(0.9),ma=c(0.2)),n = 100)
   ```

   estimate the model from arma.sim, assuming we know it is a (1,0,1) model

   ```
   arma.est1 <- arima(arma.sim, order=c(1,0,1))
   ```
2. also say we get arma.est1 in this form, which is close to the original (0.9,0,0.2):

   ```
   Coefficients:
    ar1     ma1  intercept
    0.9115  0.0104    -0.4486
   s.e.  0.0456  0.1270     1.1396

   sigma^2 estimated as 1.15:  log likelihood = -149.79,  aic = 307.57
   ```
3. If I try to reconstruct another time series from `arma.est1`, how do I incorporate intercept or s.e. in `arima.sim`? Something like this doesn't seem to work well because `arma.sim` and `arma.rec` are far off:

   ```
   arma.rec <- arima.sim(n=100, list(ar=c(0.9115),ma=c(0.0104)))
   ```

Normally we use `predict()` to check the estimate. But is this a legit way to look at the estimate?

Comment: A simple solution is to manually add a constant after simulating arima using arima.sim. Arima in forecast function has the option to let you specify constant term.